# Facebook tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: facebook, analytics

Does anybody know how to track Facebook traffic (no ads) back to the original user/post, im using Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that will likely not be possible at all.

Facebook does not link to outside URLs directly, but always redirects users there via their “Link Shim” - details about that can be found here, https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/link-shim-protecting-the-people-who-use-facebook-from-malicious-urls/10150492832835766/

They take a couple of measures there to protect against leaking of any personal user info.

> […] we use the link shim's address as the referer instead of your Timeline URL (or the URL of whatever page you were on), to protect your information. By using the link shim as the referrer address, it's easier to ensure that the information in the link shim url does not contain personally identifying information.

(And it probably makes it easier for Facebook to track who clicks what when and where at the same time. Not necessarily data they’d want to share with the competition, I suppose.)

Comment: thanks, I've been doing some research and apparently there is no way except just browsing online, hah